# How do I implement an interface which is both callable, and has properties in TypeScript?

Tags: casting, typescript, type-conversion, typescript1.6

Given the interface

```
interface FooWithBar {
    ():void;
    bar():void;
}
```

how do I write the implementation?

```
function foo(){

}
foo.bar = function(){

};
```

does not work, as it throws the error, "Property 'bar' does not exist on type '() => void". But, if I declare the type of `foo` to be `FooWithBar`

````
    var foo: FooWithBar = function () {

```
};
foo.bar = function () {

};
```

````

I get another error, "Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'FooWithBar'. Property 'bar' is missing in type '() => void'".

How do I solve this catch-22?

Answer (score 2):

```
function FooWithBar() {
  // ...
}
module FooWithBar { // n.b. can use 'namespace' keyword here instead of 'module' if you like
  export function bar() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is some text to avoid ending up in the "code-only answers" review queue.

Comment: if I call FooWithBar(), I suspect that it is no longer an invokable function? Eg, what if I want to declare the Angular 1.x `$timeout` service in TypeScript? It is both invokable (wrapper for `window.setTimeout()`) but also has static methods (like `.cancel()`). Are you suggesting that one would write `module $timeout` in a Typescript implementation?

Comment: What do you mean "no longer an invokable function" ? Have you tried simply running the above code (with some code in the function body) ?

Comment: My apologies. Missed the declaration of the function in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this:

Assuming that the interface is as follows:

```
interface FooWithBar
{
    ():void;
    bar():void;
}
```

#### Namespace Exports

```
function FooWithBar(){

}
namespace FooWithBar{
    export function bar(){

    }
}
```

#### Casting

```
let foo:FooWithBar = function(){

} as FooWithBar;
foo.bar = function(){

};
```

The `namespace` keyword cannot be used in function bodies, so if you need a `foo` factory, use the second method.